# Jasmine : How to SpyOn a method callback : method.then()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, spyon

within my Angular 4.0.0 app , i have this method , called in my component.

This method is called within a service :

```
    this.myService.myMethod(param).then(any => {
        console.log("success case")
    })
      .catch(error => {
            console.log("error");
        }
      });
  };
```

Since i'm working on unit testing , i'm isolating my component via mocking the service : i'm mocking then this method , like the following :

```
myMethodSpy= spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.callFake((reg) => {
    return Observable.of('always error message');
});
```

But when executing , its seems that my spyMethod isn't called:

> TypeError: this.service.myMethod(...).then is not a function

*Any ideas , about the problem's origin ?*

Comment: Observables don't have a then() method. Promises do. Check the documentation/code/return type of your service method, and verify that it returns a Promise. Return a fake promise in your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const pMock = {then: () => 'something'}
myMethodSpy= spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(pMock);
```

Or you can return an actual promise.

```
const pMock = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(someValue); 
  // or reject("failure reason"); 
});
myMethodSpy= spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(pMock);
```

Comment: Your promise could simply be created using `Promise.resolve(someValue)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: @Guy Yogev my method supports alos a catch callback (myMethod().then().catch() ) any idea of how spy on the catch block ?? )